# io.smallrye.mutiny.TimeoutException when using kafka vs redis

Tags: java, apache-kafka, redis, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I'm using kafka + redis in my project.

I get message from Kafka, process and save to redis, but it is giving error like below when my code runs after some time my code

```
    io.smallrye.mutiny.TimeoutException
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniBlockingAwait.await(UniBlockingAwait.java:64)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait.atMost(UniAwait.java:65)
    at io.quarkus.redis.client.runtime.RedisClientImpl.await(RedisClientImpl.java:1046)
    at io.quarkus.redis.client.runtime.RedisClientImpl.set(RedisClientImpl.java:687)
    at worker.redis.process.implementation.ProductImplementation.refresh(ProductImplementation.java:34)
    at worker.redis.Worker.refresh(Worker.java:51)
    at 
 kafka.InComingProductKafkaConsume.lambda$consume$0(InComingProductKafkaConsume.java:38)
    at business.core.hpithead.ThreadStart.doRun(ThreadStart.java:34)
    at business.core.hpithead.core.NotifyingThread.run(NotifyingThread.java:27)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

```
The record 51761 from topic-partition 'mer-outgoing-master-item-0' has waited for 153 seconds to be acknowledged. This waiting time is greater than the configured threshold (150000 ms). At the moment 2 messages from this partition are awaiting acknowledgement. The last committed offset for this partition was 51760. This error is due to a potential issue in the application which does not acknowledged the records in a timely fashion. The connector cannot commit as a record processing has not completed.
```

```
    @Incoming("mer_product")
    @Blocking
    public CompletionStage<Void> consume2(Message<String> payload) {
      var objectDto = configThreadLocal.mapper.readValue(payload.getPayload(), new TypeReference<KafkaPayload<ItemKO>>(){});
      worker.refresh(objectDto.payload.castDto());
      return payload.ack();
    }
```

Comment: Well, the Kafka Consumer will need a heartbeat/commit timeout that is longer than then Redis timeout if you want to avoid Kafka errors. Otherwise, seems you need to debug your Redis connection

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for correcting my spelling and also my problem